# MySQL asynchronous multi master replication conflict resolution

Tags: mysql, replication

I have setup Multi Master replication, following this blog thread:

http://0wned.it/geek-bits/guides/mysql-multi-master-replication/

And now it synchronizes perfectly, up until the moment the connection between the servers is lost. When I have no connection both servers still update fields. This results in the following problem:

- connection is lost.
- server1 updates a field to the value "bike".
- server2 updates the same field a few seconds later to the value "car"
- connection restored
- server1 gets the value "car" from server2 and updates the field
- server2 gets the value "bike" from server 1 and updates the field.

Is there a way to check if the value has already has been changed and neglect the update based on time of update? In the field on both servers the value "car" should be the current value.

Answer (score 4):

Conflict-free replication isn't supported in multi-source replication...

You should look at cluster multi-master setup, but, I don't know a multi-master cluster with lazy updates (async-replication).

Comment: @spambas Galera, on its multiples vendors is precisely a provider of this. It is not fully asynchronous (writes are always syncronous), but not fully synchronous (read lag is configurable) "virtualy synchronous". It can auto-update, but not while being "offline". It discards older, incompatible transactions. If you want to continue with standard replication, what you need to fix is your load balancing policy (a proxy may help).